# Scanning for enclosed spaces

Tags: java, recursion, math, geometry, minecraft

This question is hard to describe, but I'm going to try my best.

Let's say theres a 2D pixelated block game. And there are blocks like this

```
□□■□□□□□□□■■■■■■■■■■□□□■■□□□□□
□□□□□□□□□□■□□□□□□□□■□□□□□□■□□□
□□□□■□□□□□■□□□□□□□□■□□□□□□□□□□
□□□□□□□□□□■■■■■■■■■■□□□□■□□□□□
□□□□■□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□■□□□□□
```

How would you go about writing something that can scan this situation and highlight the white blocks that are enclosed, like this:

```
□□■□□□□□□□■■■■■■■■■■□□□■■□□□□□
□□□□□□□□□□■⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛■□□□□□□■□□□
□□□□■□□□□□■⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛■□□□□□□□□□□
□□□□□□□□□□■■■■■■■■■■□□□□■□□□□□
□□□□■□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□■□□□□□
```

Now, the part that I'm even more interested in, is doing the same thing in 3D. I'm going to use Minecraft to help demonstrate 
[How could you programmatically detect this enclosed space and highlight all the blocks from it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz2z7.jpg)

Comment: Flood-fill algorithm?

Comment: Flood-fill.. the thing that MS-Paint's fill bucket uses! Yes, but in 3D

Comment: Are you asking us to write a 3D flood fill for you because you don't want to enhance the the 2D flood fill logic to 3D yourself, or do the research to see if the logic for that is available online? If not, then what are you asking?

Comment: There's one major issue with flood fill for this. In the event that the box does have a hole in it, it will fill the entire "world" which is extremely bad. You might say "just don't start the algorithm outside of an enclosure" but then we're right back to the original problem of programmatically detecting that.

Comment: You need a maximum size anyway. Otherwise, someone could build a box around the entire Minecraft world, which technically is such an enclosure, then your algorithm would have to fill the whole world without such a limit.